# Follow my location if user does not update camera manually - Google maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am working with google maps in my Android app.
I want to animate camera inside onLocationChange by default and every time the user clicks My location button. But if the user moves camera manually, I want to stop updating camera to current location.
Actually, I am always updating the camera:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   googleMap.animateCamera(map.getCamera(location));
}
```

Maybe using a boolean var but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track.

Define:

```
private boolean followUser;
```

add check:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (followUser) {
        googleMap.animateCamera(map.getCamera(location));
    }
}
```

in `onMyLocationButtonClick`:

```
followUser = true;
```

and last thing, you need to make sure when user starts interacting with the map, you stop following, so add an overlay e.g.:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <MapView />
    <View />
</FrameLayout>
```

and add `OnTouchListener` to that `View`, where you do:

```
followUser = false;
return false;
```

Comment: Problem is zoom does not change the camera position.  I.E. it would be nice to follow the user until there is a manual pan event.  I have not found a solution to listen to a pan gesture which sucks.